# Installing ubuntu-sdk requires cdrom. I have liveUSB

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-sdk, live-environment

While installing ubuntu-sdk, the following is the output.

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
'Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I don't have the cd but I have a liveUSB. How to mount the usb in the /cdrom? Or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've followed the steps described [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) and I didn't got any message about the cdrom, etc. I would check the entries in your sources.list and verify that the entries pointing to the installation media are commented out:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep cdrom
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main multiverse restricted universe
```

The entry should start with `#`.